# ¿Cómo mostrar contenido en una tabla segun id ?(php y mysqli)

Tags: php, html, mysqli, web

Hola buenas tardes espero que estén bien bueno tengo una duda tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
include('./conexion.php');
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ip_pc WHERE id_user=$id";
    $conexion = Conexion::Conectar();
    $result = $conexion->prepare($query);
    $result->execute();
    $usuarios = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

El cual hace o realiza una consulta después por id el cual trae los datos y después en el html imprimo en una tabla de esta forma:

```
<div class='container' >
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-light">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>NOMBRE USUARIO</th>
          <th>NOMBRE DE IP</th>
          <th>IP</th>
          <th>ESTADO DE ACCESO</th>
          <th>INTERACCIONES</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $usuarios['nombre_completo']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $usuarios['nombre_ip']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $usuarios['ip']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $usuarios['estado']; ?></td>
    <td display="inline-block" ;>
      <a href="php/editUsersIp.php?id=<?php echo $usuarios['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-warning" type="button">editar</a>
      <a href="php/delate2.php?id=<?php echo $usuarios['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">eliminar</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
   
</table>
</div>
```

Pero mi problema es que **no me muestra todos los datos que hay por ese id y solo me muestra el primero** como los puedo mostrar todos los datos que hay por ese id

Comment: Consulta: estas hablando de un error en MySQLi, pero tú código es con PDO?

Comment: @rpaillao no la consulta esta perfecta a lo que me refiero es como se muestra cuando lo intento mostrar los datos solo me muestra el primer dato de la consulta y no todos y que la sintaxis de la consulta esta bien realizada porque la probé en 
mysql y si trae los datos como es  pero no me los muestra todos solo el primero de la consulta

Comment: si es un una tabla con un ciclo while puedes hacerlo

Comment: @steven me podrías dar una idea o ejemplo de como hacer ese while yo soy de phyton pero mi jefe me puso en este proyecto y se muy poco de php

Comment: [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php) puedes ver como trabajar las iteraciones con PDO

Comment: @JuanFelipeCorreaRíos ya publique el ejemplo verifica si es asi como lo necesitas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('./conexion.php');
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ip_pc WHERE id_user={$id}";
    $conexion = Conexion::Conectar();
    $result = $conexion->prepare($query);
    $result->execute();
    
}
?>

   <div class='container' >
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-light">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>NOMBRE USUARIO</th>
          <th>NOMBRE DE IP</th>
          <th>IP</th>
          <th>ESTADO DE ACCESO</th>
          <th>INTERACCIONES</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        
<tbody>
<?php while($usuario = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){ ?>


     
       <tr>
  <td><?php echo $usuario['nombre_completo']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $usuario['nombre_ip']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $usuario['ip']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $usuario['estado']; ?></td>
  <td display="inline-block" ;>
   <a href="php/editUsersIp.php?id=<?php echo $usuario['id'] ?>" class="btn 
    btn-warning" type="button">editar</a>
  <a href="php/delate2.php?id=<?php echo $usuario['id'] ?>" class="btn btn- 
   danger" type="button">eliminar</a>
 </td>

      </tr>
<?php } ?>
 </tbody>
   
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que de la forma actual solamente estas obteniendo el primer valor del array que estas obteniendo, para esto vamos a utilizar lo que seria un ciclo `foreach()` que devuelve los valores del array indexado con los nombres de las columnas, para eso tambien vamos a modificar tu codigo manteniendo el procediento PDO, al cambiar `$result->fetch()` por `$result->fetchAll()`:

```
<?php
include('./conexion.php');
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ip_pc WHERE id_user=$id";
    $conexion = Conexion::Conectar();
    $result = $conexion->prepare($query);
    $result->execute();
    $usuarios = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
```

despues ejecutamos el ciclo foreach de la siguiente manera

```
<tbody>
 <?php foreach($usuarios as $usuario) {?>
 <tr>
  <td><?=$usuario['nombre_completo']?></td>
  <td><?=$usuario['nombre_ip']?></td>
  <td><?=$usuario['ip']?></td>
  <td><?=$usuario['estado']?></td>
  <td display="inline-block">
   <a href="php/editUsersIp.php?id=<?=$usuario['id']?>" class="btn 
    btn-warning" type="button">editar</a>
  <a href="php/delate2.php?id=<?=$usuario['id']?>" class="btn btn- 
   danger" type="button">eliminar</a>
 </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

y asi te tendria que funcionar el codigo!